# Blank white after PHP form submission

Tags: php

I'm really new to PHP and having trouble figuring out how to troubleshoot. I've looked at lot of other issues having similar problems, but I can't get the solutions they're giving to work in my code.

When you submit a form on the following page, the email is sent just as it should be, but the page turns white. I've changed it to target _blank so it makes a new tab that's white, but it's still confusing people.

The webpage is at: http://designbycrisscross.com/contact.html

And here's the contents of contact.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

$to = 'neena@designbycrisscross.com'; 
$subject = 'New Email from CrissCross Website';
$from = $email;

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Budget: $budget\n Message:\n $message";

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);
if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {

if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
echo 'Your message has been sent!';
} else { 
echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
} 

} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you don't post PHP code, we cannot help.

Comment: Most likely: You haven't written any PHP that (after you send the mail) outputs an HTML document to be displayed instead of a plain white page.

Comment: As said above, you probably don't output anything, so try adding some echo statements at the end of the file to see if it reaches the end of the page

Comment: `@mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);` remove `@` in front of the function call. This is error suppression and probably the reason why you see a white page instead of errors.

Comment: I removed the `@`; thanks for explaining that. However, the page is acting the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

If the mail is being sent, then the only possible explanation is that $_POST['submit'] == false (unlikely) or $human != '4' (more likely).

Reasoning: mail($to, $subject, $body, $from) is running on line 14, but it's not making it past the conditional on line 15. If it were to make it past the conditional on line 15, it would have to output at least something.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your conditional to provide more information.

```php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($human == '4') {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo 'Your message has been sent!';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
} else {
    trigger_error('Form submission not detected!', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. Thanks. I'll see if this fixes it.